# calculating the area of a triangle on the hyperbolic plane with vertices (−1, 0),(0, 0) and (1, 0).

Tags: geometry

In my notes the hyperbolic plane is defined as $\{x+iy : y>0 \}$.

I know I need to use the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem: $\text{Area} =  \pi - A - B - C$
but I'm not sure how to calculate the angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ (I think they are identical in this case).

I also know that: $\tanh({d\over2}) = {|z-w|\over|z-w^*|}$ where $d$ is the distance between $z$ and $w$, and $w^*$ is the conjugate of $w$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The vertices of the triangle are on the line at infinity, so the triangle is an ideal triangle. Therefore, two geodesics meeting at an ideal point are represented by a pair of semi-circles (in this case, or a vertical line and a circle sometimes) with centers on the real line. Two such circles are tangnet to each other, so the angle between them is $0$. Hence, by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem the area of the triangle is $\pi - 0 - 0 - 0 = \pi$.

By the way, any two ideal triangles in the hyperbolic plane are congruent, i.e. there exists a hyperbolic isometry that maps one ideal triangle to the other. That's because any three points on the real line can be mapped to any other tree points by the isometry group ${P}SL(2.\mathbb{R})$.